# How to combine two rows values into one in power bi using DAX and not in Power Query?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with name "Business Unite" as below -

| Business Unit |
| --- |
| A.1 |
| A.2 |
| A.3 |
| B |
| C |

I want the values for the rows A.1, A.2 and A.3 to be as A only.
The new table should look like the below example -

| Business Unit |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |

I have tried the below DAX expression but obviously, it has an error -

```
Business Unite Measure = 
CALCULATETABLE( 'Events', 
        SWITCH( 'Events'[Business Unit], 
                "A.1", "A",
                "A.2", "A",
                "A.3", "A",
                "B", "B",
                "C", "C", BLANK() ) )
```

The desired table is achievable in Power Query but is there any way to get the result using DAX?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/calculatetable-function-dax. … you may want to look up for a calculated column or how to create a table with DAX

Comment: Dear, calculated column or measure or any table function would require context. Please go through the question, there is no context for groping rows. BTW, I have the link you shared.

Comment: Dear, if you have the link, why you would post your DAX expression anyway? You can create context/reference from your current business unit table. No grouping needed. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new **column** in table *(note that should be column not measure)*:

```
Business Unit2 = 
SWITCH( [Business Unit], 
"A.1", "A",
"A.2", "A",
"A.3", "A",
"B", "B",
"C", "C", BLANK() )
```

Then you can use this new column as X-axis & other value measures as Y-axis to any visuals.

Comment: But making a calculated column in the fact table is not a smart move.

Comment: One issue is there if you create a Measuer. You can not use that in a Slicer. But you can create a Column using logic like removing everything started from Dot (.) in the value.

Answer (score 1):

Here answer for your measure calculation:

If you want measure the formula would be:

```
Business Unite Measure = 
SWITCH( SELECTEDVALUE('Events'[Business Unit]), 
"A.1", "A", 
"A.2", "A", 
"A.3", "A", 
"B", "B", 
"C", "C", 
BLANK() )
```

But as Rabbani mentioned you cannot use this measure as Slicer or X-axis or Y-axis, if you want to show in table you should use it with original [Business Unit] column in table visual. Otherwise the created measure will not show.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option write here as add comment in previous answer cannot make newline may not so clear:

**Step 1:**
Create value measure for any values you want to see:

```
Value Measure = SUM(Events[Value])
```

**Step 2:**
Create new table:

```
New Table = DATATABLE("Business Unit2",STRING,
{{"A"},{"B"},{"C"}})
```

**Step 3:**
Create new column in new table:

```
Value - Version 1 = SWITCH([Business Unit2],
"A",CALCULATE([Value Measure],SEARCH("A",'Events'[Business Unit],1,0)>0),
"B",CALCULATE([Value Measure],SEARCH("B",'Events'[Business Unit],1,0)>0),
"C",CALCULATE([Value Measure],SEARCH("C",'Events'[Business Unit],1,0)>0))

Value - Version 2 = SWITCH([Business Unit2],
"A",CALCULATE([Value Measure],
'Events'[Business Unit]="A.1"||
'Events'[Business Unit]="A.2"||
'Events'[Business Unit]="A.3"),
"B",CALCULATE([Value Measure],'Events'[Business Unit]="B"),
"C",CALCULATE([Value Measure],'Events'[Business Unit]="C"))
```

*Results as below:*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column and use the following formula:

```
column = left(Table[Vusiness Unit], 1)
```